# Override an original android xml file

Tags: android

I understand that this is the original layout for Snackbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              ...
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
              ...
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</merge>
```

Is it possible to override an original android layout such as this one?

Comment: No, it is not. I gave Snackbar as an example. I am not asking about Snackbar itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite but it is possible to change the original layout file. Generally all the default xml layout files are stored in system path.In my window `C:\Users\NAVEEN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platforms\android-22\data\res\layout`system it is . So you can change that xml content and reuse it in your app